#  Need help figuring out logic to manipulate data in a local table (SQL)

Tags: sql

I have a table which looks like the follwing.

```
EMPLID EFFDT    EFFSEQ     DEPTID   JOBCODE FLAG1     FLAG2      FLAG3
  X    <date>   <number>   <text>   <text>  <number>  <number>   <number>
  X                         
  Y                         
  Z    <date1>  <number1>  <text1>  <text1> <number1>  <number1>  <number1>
  Z    <date2>  <number2>  <text2>  <text2> <number2>  <number2>  <number2>
  Z
```

What I'm not able to figure out is, how to eliminate the 2nd and the last row while managing to keep the 3rd row (`EMPLID=Y`)

In words, I need to eliminate records of employees where there is one with full population and keep the ones which is the only one which is empty. This is a part of a much larger problem I'm having to face. I wish I had the time to discuss the whole problem.

Thank you

Comment: **What** database system, and which version?? **SQL** is just the Structured Query Language - a language used by many database systems - SQL is **NOT** a database product... stuff like this is very often vendor-specific - so we really need to know what database system you're using....

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL - How can I remove duplicate rows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18932/sql-how-can-i-remove-duplicate-rows)

Comment: I have a local table in access. I need to know logically, how i could go about doing that I asked above.

Answer (score 0):

You need a 'DELETE DUPE' query.  The idea behind this type of query is to group rows by some unique key, order by either primary key or maybe a date time field, then delete everything except the first one, or the last one.  If you need to isolate groups that have duplicates, add a `HAVING` clause (i.e. `having count(*) > 1`)

Here's one on SO:

[T-SQL: Deleting all duplicate rows but keeping one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6025367/t-sql-deleting-all-duplicate-rows-but-keeping-one)

```
with cte as (   
  select [foo], [bar],       
    row_number() over (partition by foo, bar order by baz) as [rn]   from table ) 
delete cte where [rn] > 1
```

If you're not using SQL Server, I'm sure there's a method to do this in almost all other DBMS.

Here's another one that's more generic on SO:

[How can I remove duplicate rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18932/sql-how-can-i-remove-duplicate-rows)

```
DELETE MyTable  
FROM MyTable 
LEFT OUTER JOIN (    
  SELECT MIN(RowId) as RowId, Col1, Col2, Col3     
  FROM MyTable     
  GROUP BY Col1, Col2, Col3 
) as KeepRows ON    MyTable.RowId = KeepRows.RowId 
WHERE    KeepRows.RowId IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the columns that you suppose to be null or not you can use :

```
DELETE TABLENAME
WHERE
EMPLID IN (
SELECT DISTINCT EMPLID
    FROM TABLENAME
WHERE EFFDT IS NOT NULL [OR EFFSEQ IS NOT NULL [...]]
) AND EFFDT IS NULL [AND EFFSEQ IS NULL [...]]
```

Answer (score -1):

I am assuming you only want to remove the rows in your query, not from the table itself:

```
select *
from MyTable
where EMPLID = 'Y'
    or coalesce(EFFDT, '') <> ''
```

Comment: Hi RedFilter. I do not understand. My table has about 50k records with a combination of cases like the emlid's x,y and z. I'm also not clear on what coalesce does. I've taken a quick look online and its not very clear.

Comment: @user `COALESCE` returns the first non-NULL value, else NULL. I am using it to convert NULLs to an empty string in this case. It is not needed if you have no NULL values. It could be replaced with `or EFFDT <> '' `