# delete duplicate rows and need to keep one from all of them in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-delete

I want to delete duplicate rows based on two columns but need to keep 1 row all of them.

Duplicate rows can be more than two rows like,

```
ID  NAME PHONE
--  ---- ----
1   NIL  1234 
2   NIL  1234 
3   NIL  1234 
4   MES  5989
```

I want to delete any of 2 rows from above 3 and keep 1 row.

Comment: Also the design is flawed... if NIL 1234 only should appear once you should make that the primary key or at least make a trigger that checks for the existance so that your database stays consistent

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
DELETE  a
FROM    tableA a
        LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT MIN(ID) ID, Name, Phone
            FROM    TableA
            GROUP   BY Name, Phone
        ) b ON  a.ID = b.ID AND
                a.NAme = b.Name AND
                a.Phone = b.Phone
WHERE   b.ID IS NULL
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/87018/1)

After you have executed the delete statement, enforce a unique constraint on the column so you cannot insert duplicate records again,

```
ALTER TABLE TableA ADD CONSTRAINT tb_uq UNIQUE (Name, Phone)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DELETE
FROM Table
WHERE Table.id NOT IN  (  
    SELECT MIN(idTable) idtable
    FROM idTable
    GROUP BY name, phone)
```

Comment: Hello Matt,

I used your query in mysql like this

`DELETE
FROM  tablename
WHERE  tablename.ID NOT IN  (  
    SELECT MIN(ID) 
    FROM tablename
    GROUP BY NAME, PHONE)`

But i am getting below error,

#1093 - You can't specify target table 'timezone' for update in FROM clause

Comment: @Neel Check the second comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6025387/2550529