# DELETE duplicate rows from a table and its corresponding data in another table in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Consider I have a table structure like this,

```
id    Email
-----------
1    abc@gmail.com
2    abc1@gmail.com
3    abc@gmail.com
4    abc@gmail.com
5    abc@gmail.com
```

And another table

```
id   userId     name
---------------------
1    1          A
2    2          B
3    3          C
4    4          D
5    5          E
```

Now if I want to remove duplicates from table 1, i.e. `2, 3, 4, 5` should be deleted from `table1` and its corresponding data in `table2`.

How would I do this?
Is this possible?

Comment: use foreign key with combination of on delete cascade. Please go through this [link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)

Comment: This might help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/15548724/2681855

Answer (score 1):

first try to delete duplicate row from user table by keeping the one using below code :

```
DELETE FROM `user` WHERE `id` NOT IN (select * from ( SELECT MIN(`id`) FROM `user` GROUP BY `email` ) as t)
```

secondly try to delete other dependent rows from another table by following :

```
DELETE FROM `user_data` WHERE `u_id` NOT IN (select * from ( SELECT MIN(`id`) FROM `user` GROUP BY `email` ) as t)
```

hope this will work for you.

Comment: Would you try with "exists"  instead of "in"?

Answer (score 0):

In a DML way, try the following query with your table (Edit it according to your tables). NOTE: Delete can be rolled back.

```
DELETE t1
FROM t1, holdkey
WHERE t1.col1 = holdkey.col1
AND t1.col2 = holdkey.col2
```

Comment: I want to fine duplicates and then delete them.

Comment: The above query is going to help you for deleting. For finding duplicates try:  
SELECT email, COUNT( * ) FROM table_name GROUP BY email HAVING COUNT( * ) > 1

For more check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2594829/finding-duplicate-values-in-a-sql-table

Comment: That i have already tried, requirement is if i can use only one query o do that??

Comment: I think my answer was enough. DELETE query is the only one way query.