# SQL: Deleting row which values already exist

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, delete-row

I have a table that look like this:

```
ID | DATE       | NAME   | VALUE_1 | VALUE_2
1  | 27.11.2015 | Homer  | A       | B
2  | 27.11.2015 | Bart   | C       | B
3  | 28.11.2015 | Homer  | A       | C
4  | 28.11.2015 | Maggie | C       | B
5  | 28.11.2015 | Bart   | C       | B
```

I currently delete duplicate rows (thank to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6025367/t-sql-deleting-all-duplicate-rows-but-keeping-one)) using this code :

```
WITH cte AS
(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [VALUE_1], [VALUE_2]
ORDER BY [DATE] DESC) RN
FROM [MY_TABLE])
DELETE FROM cte
WHERE RN > 1
```

But this code don't delete exactly the lines I want. I would like to delete only rows which values already exist so in my example I would like to delete only line 5 because line 2 have the same values and is older.

Code to create my table and insert values:

```
CREATE TABLE [t_diff_values]
([id] INT IDENTITY NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
[date] DATETIME NOT NULL,
[name] VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
[val1] CHAR(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
[val2] CHAR(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '');

INSERT INTO [t_diff_values] ([date], [name], [val1], [val2]) VALUES
('2015-11-27','Homer',  'A','B'),
('2015-11-27','Bart',   'C','B'),
('2015-11-28','Homer',  'A','C'),
('2015-11-28','Maggie', 'C','B'),
('2015-11-28','Bart',   'C','B');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add one more `CTE` where you will index all islands and then apply your duplicate logic in second `CTE`:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE
    (
      ID INT ,
      DATE DATE ,
      VALUE_1 CHAR(1) ,
      VALUE_2 CHAR(1)
    )

INSERT  INTO @t
VALUES  ( 1, '20151127', 'A', 'B' ),
        ( 2, '20151128', 'C', 'B' ),
        ( 3, '20151129', 'A', 'B' ),
        ( 4, '20151130', 'A', 'B' );
WITH    cte1
          AS ( SELECT   * ,
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY date)
                        - ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY VALUE_1, VALUE_2 ORDER BY DATE) AS gr
               FROM     @t
             ),
        cte2
          AS ( SELECT   * ,
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY VALUE_1, VALUE_2, gr ORDER BY date) AS rn
               FROM     cte1
             )
    DELETE  FROM cte2
    WHERE   rn > 1

SELECT  *
FROM    @t
```

Comment: I made a mistake, in my initial example I want to delete line 4 but not line 3. Can you please update the code while I change my question :)))

Comment: @JuGuSm, I have removed `DESC` in orderings.

Comment: I'm sorry but when I add the name column it change everything and I can't adapt your code :/

Comment: @JuGuSm, I will have a look.

Comment: @JuGuSm, change `PARTITION BY VALUE_1, VALUE_2` to `PARTITION BY [name], [val1], [val2]` in two places. Is this helpful? If not describe why?

Comment: This is what I tried but it doesn't delete any lines :/
rn=1 for every lines and the code is DELETE  FROM cte2 WHERE   rn > 1

Comment: @JuGuSm, in your sample all rows are distinct, so nothing will be deleted.

Comment: lines 2 and 5 are the same exept the date but this is the point: I would like to keep the last statut ; the line 5 (28.11.2015) is useless because the value didn't change since the 27.11.2015

Comment: @JuGuSm, initial question was different. Then I think you can use your own code `WITH cte AS
(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Name], [VALUE_1], [VALUE_2]
ORDER BY [DATE]) RN
FROM [MY_TABLE])
DELETE FROM cte
WHERE RN > 1`

Answer (score 1):

You could use this query:

```
WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) 
    , *
    FROM @data
)
DELETE FROM c1
--SELECT * 
FROM CTE c1
INNER JOIN CTE c2 ON c1.RN +1 = c2.RN AND c1.VALUE_1 = c2.VALUE_1 AND c1.VALUE_2 = c2.VALUE_2
```

Here I order them by ID. If the next one (RN+1) has similar V1 and V2, it is deleted.

**Output:**

```
ID  DATE        VALUE_1 VALUE_2
1   2015-11-27  A       B
2   2015-11-28  C       B
4   2015-11-30  A       B
```

**Data:**

```
declare @data table(ID int, [DATE] date, VALUE_1 char(1), VALUE_2 char(1));
insert into @data(ID, [DATE], VALUE_1, VALUE_2) values
(1, '20151127', 'A', 'B'), 
(2, '20151128', 'C', 'B'), 
(3, '20151129', 'A', 'B'), 
(4, '20151130', 'A', 'B');
```

Comment: I tried your code and I get this error :
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 17
Invalid column name 'VALUE_1'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 17
Invalid column name 'VALUE_1'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 17
Invalid column name 'VALUE_2'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 17
Invalid column name 'VALUE_2'.

Comment: I have tried this and it seems to work to. The code is a little shorter and clearer, but performs slightly worse then mine.

Comment: I haven't check performances. Mine may need to be tweaked if the data requirements are not what they seem to be from the question. Yours seems more versatile.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Employee](
    [ID] INT NOT NULL,
    [Date] DateTime NOT NULL,
    [VAL1] varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    [VAL2] varchar(20) NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Employee] VALUES 
            (1,'2015-11-27 10:44:33.087','A','B')
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Employee] VALUES
            (2,'2015-11-28 10:44:33.087','C','B')
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Employee] VALUES
            (3,'2015-11-29 10:44:33.087','A','B') 
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Employee] VALUES
            (4,'2015-11-30 10:44:33.087','A','B')

with cte as(
    select
        *,
        rn = row_number() over(partition by [VAL1], [VAL2]
ORDER BY [DATE] DESC),
        cc = count(*) over(partition by [VAL1], [VAL2])
    from [Employee]
)

delete
from cte
where
    rn > 1 and rn < cc

select * from [Employee]
```

Comment: @JuGuSm, You just accepted incorrect solution! Just try it on `VALUES  ( 1, '20151126', 'A', 'B' ),
        ( 2, '20151127', 'C', 'B' ),
        ( 3, '20151128', 'A', 'B' ),
        ( 4, '20151129', 'D', 'B' ),
        ( 5, '20151130', 'A', 'B' );`  All rows are different but this solution deletes rows.

Comment: @SabyasachiMishra, ordering will not correct the situation. Also ordering in Count is supported only in 2012+ versions

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri you're right! I tried and it delete a line while it should not because there isn't two identicals and followed lines. I try your solution with same values.