# Optimise SQL request for duplicate Value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have an `INSEE` table in my SQL Server 2008 R2. I have some duplicate values (15 000 lines out of 54 000 have to be deleted). This is my current script

```
    declare @datainsee table
    (
        di_nom varchar(100),
        di_departement varchar(5),
        di_type varchar
    )
    declare @datainseeidentifiant table
    (
        dii_nom varchar(100),
        dii_departement varchar(5),
        dii_type varchar,
        dii_identifiant uniqueidentifier
    )
    insert into @datainsee select iee_nom,iee_departement,iee_type from insee
    group by iee_nom,iee_departement,iee_type 
    having(count(*)>1)

    insert into @datainseeidentifiant 
    select di_nom,di_code,di_type,
    (select top 1 iee_guid from insee where iee_departement=di_departement and iee_nom=di_nom and iee_type= di_type) from @datainsee

    delete from insee
    where iee_guid not in (select dii_identifiant from @datainseeidentifiant) and iee_nom in (select dii_nom from @datainseeidentifiant)
```

Rows are considered as duplicate if they have the same `iee_nom`, `iee_departement` and `iee_type`.
I tried to look at solutions like [T-SQL: Deleting all duplicate rows but keeping one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6025367/t-sql-deleting-all-duplicate-rows-but-keeping-one) but it doesn't work in my case because `GUID` is not number..

Any ideas to optimise my query? One minute is too long for my application.

Comment: do you have auto generated  ID column in table?

Comment: No, Only GUID as uniqueidentifier.
No primary key no ID.. 
I know it is bad but application was create before I come and it is old version of application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the help of a CTE and ROW_NUMBER.

This should be enough:

```
with x as (
select
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
        PARTITION BY
            iee_nom, iee_departemen, iee_type
        ORDER BY
            <pick your priority column here>
    )rID,
    *
from insee
)
delete from x where rID > 1
```

Comment: Dont work for me..
Msg 252 - Recursive common table expression 'insee' does not contain a top-level UNION ALL operator.

Comment: @ErenAtolgan what name did you give to the CTE? insee? give it a different name like i did in the example. And do your delete over that alias.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use traditional way like below, Using `Temp` Table

```
SELECT DISTINCT * INTO #TmpTable FROM insee

DELETE FROM insee
--OR Use Truncate to delete records

INSERT INTO insee  SELECT * FROM #TmpTable

DROP TABLE #TmpTable
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have ID(Auto increment primary key) column in table.

```
DELETE n1 FROM insee n1
        INNER JOIN
    insee n2 ON n1.iee_nom = n2.iee_nom
        AND n1.iee_departement = n2.iee_departement
        AND n1.iee_type = n2.iee_type
        AND n1.id > n2.id;
```

Comment: Work great only int.. Like I use uniqueidentifier it delete all values but I copy for the new version.