# Delete except max records on duplicate

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table like below format,

```
Item_Txn       Item_Name
101            Mouse
102            Mouse
103            Mouse
104            Keyboard
105            CPU
106            Monitor
107            Monitor
```

I want to delete duplicate items except max Item_Txn. For eg., Mouse is duplicate items(3 times). I want to delete Mouse record except (103, Mouse).

Comment: This is called DeDup.  You will find plenty of techniques online as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [T-SQL: Deleting all duplicate rows but keeping one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6025367/t-sql-deleting-all-duplicate-rows-but-keeping-one)

Answer (score 4):

For SQL Server 2008 and newer:

```
;WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT      Item_Txn, Item_Name,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Item_Name ORDER BY Item_Txn DESC) AS RowNumber
    FROM        my_table
)

DELETE FROM cte
    WHERE RowNumber > 1
```

Answer (score 2):

```
DELETE a
FROM   my_table a
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT *
               FROM   my_table b
               WHERE  a.Item_Name = b.Item_Name
                 AND  b.Item_Txn > a.Item_Txn);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
DELETE  FROM MyTable
WHERE   Item_Txn IN (
    SELECT  K.Item_Txn
    FROM    ( SELECT    Item_Txn ,
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY Item_Name ORDER BY Item_Txn DESC ) AS RN
              FROM      MyTable
            ) AS K
    WHERE   K.RN > 1 );
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
delete from table 
where Item_Txn not in
         (select max(Item_Txn) from table group by Item_Name)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DELETE t
FROM YourTable t
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT MAX(Item_Txn) as Item_Txn
    FROM YourTable  t1
    WHERE t1.Item_Name = t.Item_Name
    ) as p
WHERE p.Item_Txn != t.Item_Txn
```

That query will left only:

```
103 Mouse
104 Keyboard
105 CPU
107 Monitor
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using an Intermediate Subquery

```
    DELETE FROM `table`
    WHERE id NOT IN (
      SELECT id
      FROM (
        SELECT id
        FROM `table`
        ORDER BY id DESC
        LIMIT 1 -- keep this many records
      ) foo
    );
```

Above is for **MySQL**

This is for **SQL**

```
    DELETE FROM chat WHERE id NOT IN 
       (SELECT TOP 50 id FROM chat ORDER BY id DESC)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    ;WITH CTE AS
    (
        SELECT MAX(Item_Txn)Item_Txn, Item_Name FROM ITEM GROUP BY Item_Name
    )
    DELETE t
    FROM ITEM t
    WHERE EXISTS
    (
        SELECT 1 FROM CTE WHERE t.Item_Name = CTE.Item_Name AND t.Item_Txn <> CTE.Item_Txn
    )
```