# how to remove a duplicate row in SQL with date condition?

Tags: sql, duplicates

my data is:

```
ID  Name    date
1   Ben 2017-01-21
2   Mark    2017-01-20
3   Mark    2017-01-21
4   Ell 2017-01-19
```

and it should be

```
ID  Name    date
1   Ben 2017-01-21
3   Mark    2017-01-21
4   Ell 2017-01-19
```

just the older "mark" with ID 2 must be remove

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 7):

If you just want to return the most recent row for name, you can use:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.date = (select max(t2.date) from t t2 where t2.name = t.name);
```

In most databases, you can use similar logic for a `delete`:

```
delete from t
    where t.date < (select max(t2.date) from t t2 where t2.name = t.name)
```

Comment: @codewing . . . The `delete` statement is deleting all rows where the date for the name is less than the maximum date for the `name`.  That appears to be the intent of the OP (if s/he really wants a `delete`).

Answer (score 0):

you can use following query. i usually avoid to add sub queries in select or where to avoid performance issues.

```
Select id, name date from mydata x
inner join (SELECT name,MAX(date) from mydata group by name) y on x.name=y.name
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the table has not been [normalized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). But as per the question following should work if the database is SQL Server 2008 and above, [credit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6025367/t-sql-deleting-all-duplicate-rows-but-keeping-one):

```
WITH cte AS (
      SELECT Id, Name, [Date]
         row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY [date]) AS [RowNum]
      FROM YourTable
    )
DELETE cte WHERE [RowNum] > 1
```