# SQL SERVER: How to delete duplicate rows in one table having one-to-many mapping with other

Tags: sql-server, database, one-to-many, sql-delete

I have a SQL Server containing duplicate rows w.r.t a particular column of a table `tableObj` which I want to delete. The query I am using is:

```
DELETE tableObj 
WHERE id NOT IN 
(SELECT MIN(id)
FROM tableObj
GROUP BY column_name);
```

This `column_name` is duplicate and I want to remove all the other rows containing the same column. Now as I execute this query, i get following error:

```
The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "some_value". The conflict occurred in database "UH", table "Test.otherTable", column 'column_name'.
```

This `otherTable` is with which there is one-to-mapping of `tableObj`. Now how do I delete these references as well along with duplicate deletion.

This is how I find the duplicates:

```
SELECT column_name, COUNT(*)
FROM tableObj
GROUP BY column_name
HAVING 
COUNT(*) > 1
```

which gives me result like:

```
column_name   (no-specific column) 
12345              2
23414              3
...........
...........
```

The mapping is persisted in the mapping table like:

```
tableObjID         otherTableId
```

The desired result after executing the `DELETE` query is to get(COUNT=1):

```
column_name   (no-specific column) 
12345              1
23414              1
...........
...........
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [T-SQL: Deleting all duplicate rows but keeping one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6025367/t-sql-deleting-all-duplicate-rows-but-keeping-one)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to delete from the `otherTable`, if the `ON DELETE CASCADE` setting enabled in the `Foreign Key constraint`

Otherwise you first need to delete the referenced data from other table, and then delete the main data from the table.

Following query should work in your case.

```
--Delete the Referenced Data
DELETE FROM otherTable
WHERE ID IN
(
  SELECT ID FROM
   ( 
    SELECT ID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY column_name ORDER BY ID) RN
    FROM tableObj
   )T WHERE T.RN>1
)
GO
--DELETING THE DUPLICATE ROWS
WITH CTE AS
(
 SELECT ID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY column_name ORDER BY ID) RN
 FROM tableObj
)
DELETE  CTE WHERE RN > 1
```