# Delete Duplicate record in sql server if 2 colums matching

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | 1 |
| A | B | 1 |
| A | B | 2 |
| A | B | 2 |
| A | c | 1 |

When col1 and Col2 values are same and Col3 values are different I dont want that values in result set.
I want result as below. I tried with row_number, group by , so manythings but did not worked. Please help me here

| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | c | 1 |

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6025367/t-sql-deleting-all-duplicate-rows-but-keeping-one

Answer (score 1):

You can use `exists`:

```
delete from t
    where exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.col1 = t.col1 and t2.col2 = t.col1 and
                        t2.col3 <> t.col3
                 );
```

You can also use window functions:

```
with todelete as (
      select t.*,
             min(col3) over (partition by col1, col2) as min_col3,
             max(col3) over (partition by col1, col2) as min_col4
      from t
     )
delete from todelete
     where min_col3 <> max_col3;
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to make these column a unique composite key. But here is a query to delete all records other than your desired result.

```
delete from Table_1 
where 
Col1=(SELECT Col1
      FROM table_1
      GROUP BY Col1, Col2
      HAVING Count(*) > 1) 
And 
Col2 =(SELECT Col2
       FROM table_1
       GROUP BY Col1, Col2
       HAVING Count(*) > 1)
```

this might not be the most optimized and efficient query but it works. if you don't want to delete duplicated records and just retrieve unique ones:

```
SELECT Col1,Col2
FROM table_1
GROUP BY Col1, Col2
HAVING Count(*) = 1
```

To get duplicating records:

```
SELECT Col2,Col1
FROM table_1
GROUP BY Col1, Col2
HAVING Count(*) > 1
```