# delete rows where id exists more than once but keep the record with the latest date stamp

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like below

```
 id     value      date
 abc     -0.4      2021-03-03
 def     0.2       2021-09-09
 abc     3.3       2000-01-01
```

I need to delete any ids that appear more than once but keep the record that has the latest date. So for eaxmple I want to run a query that would leave me a table like below,

```
 id     value      date
 abc     -0.4      2021-03-03
 def     0.2       2021-09-09
```

How do I write a delete query to delete records where the id exists more than once but keep the latest record?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A nice solution in SQL Server is an updatable CTE using a window function:

```
with todelete as (
      select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by date desc) as seqnum
      from t
     )
delete from todelete
    where seqnum > 1;
```

Comment: *cough* [Exact duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6025929/2029983) *cough*