# In a same table how to find Duplicate combination Column values are there or not?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have one table called ServiceCodes in that havings Columns like Customer, companyId, ServiceCode, CompanySourc, NewlyInserted. I have to insert some records into this table. On that time I am inserting same customer and serviceCode values into that table. On that item I am updating this NewlyInserted bit into 1. By using this is there any way to get those Duplicated rows?
And after that I want to remove those duplicated rows. In SSMS SQL
example in ServiceCodes table

```
custID1,compid1,Service1233,CompSource1,0
custID2,compid1,Service1234,CompSource1,0
custID3,compid1,Service1235,CompSource1,0
custID4,compid1,Service1236,CompSource1,0
custID3,compid1,Service1235,CompSource1,1
custID4,compid1,Service1236,CompSource1,1
```

How to find these two rows servicecode and CustId combination are already there in that ServiceCodes table? I have tried `Inner Join` and `Cross apply` and all, it is not working for me.

EDIT:

```
UPDATE Servicecodes  
            SET isNeedstobeDelete = 1
            FROM Servicecodes
            CROSS APPLY (SELECT distinct Client,ServiceCode FROM Servicecodes WHERE NewlyInserted = 0) AS ApplicableClients
            WHERE
                NewlyInserted = 1
                AND [Servicecodes].Client= [ApplicableClients].Client
                AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @tempservicecodes 
                WHERE [Servicecodes].servicecode = [ApplicableClients].servicecode 
                AND [Servicecodes].clientid = [ApplicableClients].clientid)

delete from servicecodes where isNeedstobeDelete = 1
```

it is taking so much time to run when data size is getting increased , so please give a solution which will take less amount of time ,please consider this aspect as well.

and there is no other conditions we have in this table.
this deletion will occur every time user cicks one button.

Comment: Almost certainly a duplicate - search for sqlserver delete duplicates in your favourite search engine.

Comment: I don't know, something like this: `select * from yourtable y where NewlyInserted = 0 and exists(select 1 from yourtable y2 where y2.custid = y.custid and y2.servicecode = y.servicecode and y2.newlyinserted = 1)` adapt by whatever where conditions you need

Comment: The suggested duplicate does not have a NewlyInserted column, so that's a different situation. Why vote to close if you haven't read the question?

Comment: @Andomar - is it your expectation that an answer be considered a duplicate only if all of the particular details match?

Comment: @BenThul: at a bare minimum the accepted answer of the suggested duplicate should answer the question being marked as a duplicate

Comment: @Andomar - [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6025367/t-sql-deleting-all-duplicate-rows-but-keeping-one/6025929#6025929) is one such question and answer. It doesn't mention a NewlyInserted column specifically but I'm pretty set that you could put that in the order by clause for the row_number calculation to achieve the desired result. I'm sure that others such candidate duplicates are similar.

Comment: @BenThul: A post-import cleanup doesn't want to touch duplicates that are already there.  AFAIK adding an `order by` clause is not enough.  (The answer you link is closed as a duplicate, and the duplicate it links to has an even less related answer that uses an ancient `delete ... left join` style and depends on a primary key.)

Comment: "I have tried Inner Join and Cross apply and all, it is not working for me" - you need to show us, and then we can help correct your statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    UPDATE @tempservicecodes
    SET isNeedstobeDelete = 1
    FROM (
        SELECT 
            MainTempServices.Client,MainTempServices.CompID,MainTempServices.ServiceCode   
        FROM @tempservicecodes MainTempServices  
        LEFT JOIN @tempservicecodes ReqTempServices 
            ON ReqTempServices.NewlyInserted = 0 
            AND MainTempServices.Client= ReqTempServices.Client
            AND MainTempServices.ServiceCode = ReqTempServices.ServiceCode  
        WHERE 
            MainTempServices.NewlyInserted = 1  
            AND ISNULL(ReqTempServices.ServiceCode, 0) = 0
    ) AS ApplicableServices  
    WHERE  
        NewlyInserted = 1  
        AND [@tempservicecodes].Client = ApplicableServices.Client  
        AND [@tempservicecodes].ServiceCode = ApplicableServices.ServiceCode   
        AND [@tempservicecodes].CompID = ApplicableServices.CompID

Delete from @tempservicecodes where isNeedstobeDelete = 1
```

Somehow, I Found this Left JOIN
It is working Fine and Performance also Pretty Good.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a subquery to check for duplicates.  SQL Server supports a `delete t1 from table1 as t1` syntax where you can assign an alias to the table you want to delete from:

```
delete  sc1
from    ServiceCodes sc1
where   sc1.NewlyInserted = 1
        and exists
        (
        select  *
        from    ServiceCodes sc2
        where   sc2.NewlyInserted = 0
                and sc1.ServiceId = sc2.ServiceId
                and sc1.CustId = sc2.CustId
        )
```

[Example at DBFiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/7aDRyEFV)

Comment: sorry , i haven't mentioned this in my question using having and not exist or exist these are all taking so much to complete one query if total num of records are high,is there any way to find wuthout using exist, because for small number of records it will be fine,but if the number of records increases performance issue will occur.

Comment: If you are having performance issues, then solve the performance issues. Re-ordering the query isn't the way to solve them.

Answer (score 0):

A solution that uses the [`ROW_NUMBER()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2016) window function to search for duplicates.

```
with
  t as (
    select
      newlyinserted,
      row_number() over(partition by ServiceId, CustId
                        order by newlyinserted) as rn
    from ServiceCodes
  )
delete from t
where newlyinserted = 1 and rn > 1;
```

Try it on [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/PNZKOpfp).

**Update:**
If you need to "delete" and "update", then you need the [`MERGE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2016) statement (all about [`OUTPUT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2016) clause).

```
with
  t as (
    select
      *,
      row_number() over(partition by CustId, ServiceId
                        order by newlyinserted) as rn
    from ServiceCodes
  )
merge into t
using (values('')) as d(d)
  on newlyinserted = 1
when matched and rn = 1 then update
  set newlyinserted = 0
when matched and rn > 1 then delete
OUTPUT $action, deleted.*;
```

Try it on [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/mcqVRH0l).

Comment: sorry , i haven't mentioned this in my question. it will be fast even if that servicecodes haing lakh num of data ? if yes then this will be fine for me.but i think select * will take a time in my opinion

Comment: @SanjayG, look at this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/database-engine/development/remove-duplicate-rows-sql-server-tab). After you updated the question, I updated my answer.